# Partially Orders

Tags: order-theory

Let $X=\{2,3,4,5,6,12,15,16,25\}$ and let $|$ be the partial order on $X$ given by divisibility. Could someone show me how to find the maximal elements, greatest element, minimal elements, and least element of $(X,|)$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I really don't even know where to start. This is the first time I've been faced with a "partial order"

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Draw yourself a [Hasse Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram).  A maximal element is an element who is not related to anything "larger" (*from our set*).  A minimal element is one where nothing "smaller" is related to it.  Note that there may be multiple maximal elements and multiple minimal elements.

Comment: There are a number of useful videos of lectures or youtubers who explain this topic.  [See this video for example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh28W8IAojU) of someone drawing a Hasse diagram similar to your example.